# Element.insertAdjacentHTML not compatible with ::before and ::after bootstrap classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to append some html string to parent element by using pure javascript functions. I am using bootstrap.css and for appending html to parent I have written following function :

```
function appendMarkUp() {    
    (typeof markup == "string") ? parentEle.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", markup)
                                : parentEle.insertBefore(markup, parentEle.firstChild);
    return parentEle;
}
```

Please check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuqyfm5h/4/).
In this example, even if 'glyphicons-ok' class is applied to button, it is also applied to div next to it:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('wrapper');
parent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', "<button class='btn btn-answer btn-primary'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'/>Answer</button><div>Next msg...</div>");
```

Wherever bootstrap inserts ::before and ::after classes, HTML is not the way it is intended to be.
Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: your problem is bit unclear. Can you please post the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In this example, even if 'glyphicons-ok' class is applied to button, it is also applied to div next to it.

Well that’s because your HTML that you are trying to insert is *invalid*:

```
<button class='btn btn-answer btn-primary'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'/>Answer</…
```

`i` can not be self-closing in HTML. Once you write that *properly*, `<i …></i>`, it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/wuqyfm5h/5/